# Ошибка при установке opencv

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

Нужно установить opencv на jupyter

На свой интерпретатор через pip спокойно это сделал.

Но вот с jupyter проблемы.

`conda install opencv-python` не работает.

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv` - не работает

пишет

`Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`

Пробовал скачать через Navigator, но там начинается бесконечная загрузка.

Пробовал методы

```
conda env create - name opencv
```

но пишет

```
usage: conda-env-script.py [-h] {create,export,list,remove,update,config} ...
conda-env-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: name opencv
```

Облазев весь интернет,только потратил кучу часов в поиске информации и начинаю проклинать тот факт, что случайно наткнулся на эту статью
[вот она](https://tproger.ru/translations/opencv-python-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте один из этих:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 opencv
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 opencv


conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 opencv
```